# Redirect to previous url except in other urls

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I want to redirect a user to the previous url when he login except when a user clicks the reset password . So if a user clicks reset password then tries to login it shouldn't redirect back to reset password page. So far when a user clicks reset password and then tries to login it I get this error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`. How can I redirect to previous url excepts in other urls like(reset-password)?

I have tried this `session(['link' => url()->previous()])->except('password-reset');` and I got an error `Call to a member function except() on null`

LoginController

```
 public function showLoginForm()
 {
 session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
 return view('auth.login');
 }
```

Route

```
 Route::post('password-reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendPasswordResetToken')->name('password.reset');
```

Comment: Guess this should probably be `session(['link' => url()->previous()->except('password-reset')]);` …?

Comment: I get this `Call to a member function except() on string` @04FS

Comment: That was merely a guess based on syntax, I don’t work with Laravel. If `url()->previous()` returns a string, then trying to apply a collection method such as `except` doesn’t make much sense. What actually causes the redirect to happen here, the fact that this gets put into the session variable named `link`? Then I guess you’d have to assign that only if the previous URL was not the one for your password reset route, check that using string comparison or whatever specific functionality Laravel might offer for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reset_route = route('password.reset');
$previous = url()->previous();
if(substr($previous, 0, strlen($reset_route)) !== $reset_route) {
    session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
}
else {
    session(['link' => route('other.route')]);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are the values of $reset_route and $previous in case the user goes to the login page after resting the password?

Comment: The value of `$reset_route` is `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset-password"` @geldek